# How to clip(mask) objects in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a large background-image in my page. Over the background-image there is a white background over it. So if I scroll, behind the menu we can see background-image scrolling. In the body, I want some objects to be clipped inside the white background(color or image is no problem). When I scroll, the white background and background-image are scrolled simultaneously. I know how to clip but not sure how to clip objects and make them move along with the scrollbars.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97XtH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use clip-path:

```
img {
  clip-path: url(#clipping);
}
```

[Full description](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)

Answer (score 0):

try this, it worked in the browser, but in fiddle it had some problems:

the HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="tall"></div>
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="square"></div>
```

the CSS:

```
body{
background-image:url(your Background image address);
margin:0;
padding:0;}
    #container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);}
    #circle{
background-image:url(your Background image address);
width:200px;
height:200px;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-o-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
z-index:99;
position:fixed;
left:50%;
top:50px;}
    #square{
width:300px;
height:300px;
position:fixed;
z-index:99;
left:100px;
top:150px;
background-image:url(your Background image address);}
    #tall{
width:100%;
height:2000px;}
```

The JS:

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundPosition=("0px"+" "+'-'+document.body.scrollTop+"px");
    document.getElementById("circle").style.backgroundPosition=("0px"+" "+'-'+document.body.scrollTop+"px");
    },1);
```

Comment: there's a minor problem in ur code. whatever the image i am taking, the background-image is clipped from the beginning of the bg-image. If i take 3 objects one below the other all the objects bg is starting from the top background color of the bg image. If u can see my posted image, top circle bg is different from bottom circle. Also these objects should scroll along with the bg-image. thank u for ur effort.